# qtip2 - infinite jumping effect while its shown

Tags: jquery, qtip2

Hello iam using qtip2 without any problems and i would like to attach user focus on some notices by classic jumping effect.

This is not about how to show qtip by transition, but about jumping qtip while its shown.

I found [position effect method](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/docs/position/#effect) in API, but i dont know how to use it to infinite loop of jumping effect.

Does anybody know?

Answer (score 0):

Not infinite though, I am currently using the below bounce effect.

```
$('#yourID').qtip({
content: {
    text: 'Your alert information!'
},
position: {
    my: 'bottom center',
    at: 'top left'
},
show: {
    ready: true
},
hide: 'unfocus',                
events: {
    show: function (event, api) {
        $(this).show("bounce", { times: 5, distance: 50 }, 1000);                           
    }
},
style: {
    classes: 'ui-tooltip-shadow ui-tooltip-red'
}
});
```